# overload resolution from magic number to int or long (in range-v3)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, range-v3

In range-v3, `view_facade` class has `begin()` function.

```
template<typename D = Derived, CONCEPT_REQUIRES_(Same<D, Derived>())>
detail::facade_iterator_t<D> begin()
{
    return {range_access::begin_cursor(derived(), 42)};
}
```

And the `range_access::begin_cursor()` is implemented like this,

```
template<typename Rng>
static RANGES_CXX14_CONSTEXPR auto begin_cursor(Rng & rng, long) // --1
RANGES_DECLTYPE_AUTO_RETURN
(
    rng.begin_cursor()
)
template<typename Rng>
static RANGES_CXX14_CONSTEXPR auto begin_cursor(Rng & rng, int) // --2
RANGES_DECLTYPE_AUTO_RETURN
(
    static_cast<Rng const &>(rng).begin_cursor()
)
```

In my VS, it looks the second function is always called.

I wonder when the magic number (42) is converted into `long` to call first function.

Comment: What's _range-v3_? And what's it's relation to the c++ standards?

Comment: `RANGES_DECLTYPE_AUTO_RETURN` is a macro which puts its argument in a decltype specifier as a return type, so it serves as an expression SFINAE, and the overload taking `long` serves as a second choice fallback

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry. I acted rashly.  range-v3(Ranges) is a one of proposal of c++1y features. you can get the source [here](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that `RANGES_DECLTYPE_AUTO_RETURN` [is defined as](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/detail/config.hpp#L35):

```
#define RANGES_DECLTYPE_AUTO_RETURN(...)                        \
    -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__)                                    \
    { return (__VA_ARGS__); }                                   \
    /**/
```

then your two overloads (after macro expansion) become:

```
template<typename Rng>
static auto begin_cursor(Rng & rng, long) // --1
    -> decltype(rng.begin_cursor())
{
    return rng.begin_cursor()
}

template<typename Rng>
static auto begin_cursor(Rng & rng, int) // --2
    -> decltype(static_cast<Rng const &>(rng).begin_cursor())
{
    return static_cast<Rng const &>(rng).begin_cursor();
}
```

When calling `begin_cursor` with an `int` argument, overload resolution finds an exact match which is the second overload. It is preferred to `long`, as this one requires a conversion of the argument expression. However, if `static_cast<Rng const &>(rng).begin_cursor()` is invalid, i.e., when member function `begin_cursor()` is not const-qualified, the expression inside the `decltype` specifier will trigger a substitution failure, therefore, the compiler will continue to search for another overload, falling back to the first function.

Answer (score 4):

```
RANGES_DECLTYPE_AUTO_RETURN
(
  static_cast<Rng const &>(rng).begin_cursor()
)
```

expands to something like

```
-> decltype(static_cast<Rng const &>(rng).begin_cursor())
   { return static_cast<Rng const &>(rng).begin_cursor(); }
```

the two `begin_cursor` have different `->decltype` return values, which gives you SFINAE.  Both overloads are considered.  If the `const` version has a SFINAE failure due to the `decltype` expression being ill-formed in the immediate context, it is eliminated, and the `long` version is picked.

If it does not, `42` prefers to convert to `int` instead of `long`.  So the `const` version is picked.

Answer (score 0):

Give the compiler a proper literal?

```
return {range_access::begin_cursor(derived(), 42l)};
```

(It is "forty-two el", not the number 421. :))